# Drupal 8.5.3 You have requested a non-existent service "entity.memory_cache"

Tags: symfony, service, drupal

I am getting an error after updating the composer.

> You have requested a non-existent service "entity.memory_cache"

Please help, I can't able to find any solution for this error please help me how can i solve this issue.

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent service "entity.memory_cache". in Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() (line 151 of core\lib\Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container.php).
Drupal\commerce_log\LogStorage::createInstance(Object, Object) (Line: 249)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->createHandlerInstance('Drupal\commerce_log\LogStorage', Object) (Line: 238)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('commerce_log', 'storage') (Line: 169)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getStorage('commerce_log') (Line: 79)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getStorage('commerce_log') (Line: 95)
Drupal\views\EntityViewsData::createInstance(Object, Object) (Line: 249)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->createHandlerInstance('Drupal\commerce\CommerceEntityViewsData', Object) (Line: 238)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getHandler('commerce_log', 'views_data') (Line: 156)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager->getHandler('commerce_log', 'views_data') (Line: 169)
views_views_data()
call_user_func_array('views_views_data', Array) (Line: 391)
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleHandler->invoke('views', 'views_data') (Line: 245)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 162)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 147)
views_theme(Array, 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 447)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'views', 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 67)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:runtime:gavias_sanbro', Object, Object, Array, 1) (Line: 253)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object, 'full') (Line: 59)
Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object, 'full') (Line: 138)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->viewMultiple(Array, 'full', NULL) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->view(Object, 'full') (Line: 96)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityViewController->view(Object, 'full', NULL) (Line: 55)
Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController->view(Object, 'full', NULL)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 151)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 68)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 664)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 51)
```

I getting this error after updating composer.

Comment: what solution for this error